# Appending user inputs in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the below script, to show me the number version of the keys that are pressed, but as you can see here in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KLV56/) I have no idea, why it is not working in fiddle. But, the I am just trying to have earlier inputs saved, because everytime I pressed a key, the previous number gets deleted and a new numbers corresponding the key pops up.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayunicode(e){
var unicode=e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode
document.getElementById("op").innerHTML = unicode;

}
</script>
<form>
<textarea onkeyup="displayunicode(event);" ></textarea>

<div id="op"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string concatenation (`+=`):

```
function displayunicode(e) {
    var unicode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode
    document.getElementById("op").innerHTML += unicode;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/KLV56/1/

Your fiddle was not working because you've added your script to `onLoad` event (see Figure below) that had hidden your function inside it. Use `no wrap` instead.

[image]

Comment: how come a 41k bothers answering this one :D . it's not silly but noobs want some reputation  you know what i mean :)

Comment: @FrozenFlame Ahahah `:D` Believe or not, even 150k+ need the damned reputation `;)`

Comment: @FrozenFlame spmetimes it is not about the reps you know, it is also about helping people out

Answer (score 3):

Change `document.getElementById("op").innerHTML = unicode;` to `document.getElementById("op").innerHTML += unicode;`